# Printing on Kydex Thermal plastic

Tags: print-production

How would I print digital images on thermal plastic sheet approximately .080 thickness and 8x8 inches square. After sheet is printed, I would also need to be able to heat the sheet for molding and be able to press the sheet around a mold. Transfer paper does not provide the result i am looking for because once heated, the image becomes sticky from the heat. I heat the plastic to approximately 330 degrees before molding.

Comment: Ultraviolet (UV) printer would leave a texture on one side of the substrate.

Comment: Hi Phil. This answer is more suited as a comment, so I converted it to one. You need some reputation to post comments on this site, I'm afraid. You can always comment on your own posts, and you can comment everywhere when your reputation reaches 50. If you have more questions about the site, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You could silkscreen w/ a suitable ink --- just print onto some suitably transparent material, use the sun to expose a photo-emulsion screen, then print.

Alternately, use a CNC machine and an engraving bit.